# PHP include menu.php

Tags: php, html, web, include

I have a menu.php where there are the include of css and js library.
I want to create a new file inside a folder admin and "include menu.php".
I tried include "../menu.php", but the references inside menu.php don't change, and obviusly the css and js file are not found.
How can I do?

menu.php

```html
<!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/timeline.css">
<script src="./js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- DATETIMEPICKER -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Hierarchy

```
menu.php
-css
-js
-admin -> newfile.php
```

Comment: [This](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#118083) might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are currently referencing the include in your code or how your server is configured but when I do this, I use the following syntax:

```
<?php include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/menu.php') ?>
```

This includes the configured root directory and then concatenates the remaining path at the end.

[This](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) might also help.

Comment: when i use include ../menu.php the source outout is like this:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" >
But it dowsn't exist because it's in ../css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: how can i create a working menu.php for file in the root and in the admin folder?

Comment: So it looks to me like it is not working because the filepath changes when it is included in the new file. 

For instance, the filepath needed to reference the include would be different on these two pages:

file.php
admin/newfile.php

This is why setting the document root on the server is important because it means you can include that file in any page and it knows to locate the include file based on it's placement to the root directory instead of the file in which it is being called.

**Can you post your code for how you are calling the include itself in newfile.php?**